# Is it "wrong" to copy a photo from an article (with photographers name and link to article) on the web and tweet it?

Tags: united-states, copyright, internet

With the word "wrong" (in the question title) I am referring to whether something is either a breach of copyright or otherwise considered "bad" behavior.

The behavior here would be copying a photo from a free article in a foreign language newspaper and tweeting it. The tweet itself would not be in same language as the original but it would include a link to the original article.

If the photo is less than 10% of the original article (meaning that this is not a question of duplicating the original article), is this illegal or otherwise considered inappropriate?

Answer (score 1):

Copyright exists in the photo in its own right. Copying it without permission is a breach unless it constitutes fair use/dealing in the tweeter's jurisdiction.